# Unable to parse JSON file using python request

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-requests

I've a peculiar issue where I download a json file from S3 bucket and then parse the JSON file to extract an ID from it and send a request to an API endpoint (with a header and payload).
This works perfectly when I hard code the json file name, but not working when the file name is passed as an argument from a function. In this case the request is getting back an empty data set. What's more interesting is, I am able to extract the relevant ID from the JSON and pass it to the request, so there is nothing wrong with the file. As I mentioned it just works perfectly when hard coded the filename.

```
@dataclass(frozen=True, eq=False, order=False)
class ParseJsonObject:
  local_folder_for_json_object: str
  json_s3_object_name: str
  headers_dict: dict

class ParseJson:
  def __init__(self,
             ssa: ParseJsonObject
             ):
    assert ssa is not None
    self.parse_credentials: ParseJsonObject = ssa

  def process_json_file(self, conn):
     ext_id_list = []
     ext_id_list_1 = []
     ext_pk_list = []
     summa_id_list = []
     portfolio_id_list = []
     local_folder_for_json_object = conn.local_folder_for_json_object
     my_json_s3_object_name = conn.json_s3_object_name
     json_file_name = os.path.join(local_folder_for_json_object, my_json_s3_object_name)

     try:
        ####### This works ###################
        # with open(r"C:\JSON\20240318T115141.213094.json.txt", "r",
        #           encoding="UTF-8") as file:

        ####### This doesn't work ###################
        with open(my_json_s3_object_name, "r", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            i = 0
            for json_array in data["data"]["records"]:
                # Store externalIds from JSON in a list
                my_array_for_externalIds = json_array['externalIds']
                # Store externalPks from JSON in a list
                my_array_for_Pks = json_array['externalPks']
                # Store externalIds.value in a string
                ext_id = my_array_for_externalIds[1]['value']
                # Store externalPks.value in a string
                ext_id_pk = my_array_for_Pks[0]['value']
                if not ext_id or len(ext_id) == 0:
                    logging.info("\n" + Back.RED + "Empty JSON file or no externalId key found in the file: %s",
                                 conn.json_s3_object_name)
                    exit(0)
                ext_id_list.append([my_array_for_externalIds[1]['value']])
                ext_id_list_1.append([my_array_for_Pks[0]['value']])
                ext_pk_list.append(ext_id_pk)
                i += 1
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logging.info("\n" + Fore.RED + "JSON object %s not found..", conn.json_s3_object_name)
    except Exception as e:
        print("\nAn error occured when opening the file....", e)

    i = 0
    total_pass = 0
    total_fail = 0

    url = r"https://123456.xbarec.com/non-prod/v1.0-0/api/direct/17/txns"
    MY_EXT_PK = None
    MY_PARAMS_DICT = None
    for item in ext_id_list:
        stp = ext_id_list[i]
        ext_pk_list_value = ext_pk_list[i]
        externalIdValue = ', '.join([str(element) for element in stp])
        MY_EXT_PK = ext_pk_list_value
        try:
            print("Constructing URL for externalPk:------>", ext_pk_list_value)
            params_dict = {
                'externalPk': f"tradeId:{ext_pk_list_value}"
            }
            MY_PARAMS_DICT = params_dict
            response = requests.get(url, headers=conn.headers_dict, params=params_dict)
            logging.info('\nresponse.json---------------->%s', response.json())
            if response.status_code == 200:
                data = response.json()
                total_pass += 1
                summa_id = data['records'][0]['summaId']
                summa_id_list.append(summa_id)
                summa_id_list.append(summa_id)
            else:
                total_fail += 1
                logging.info(Back.RED + "\nAPI Response Error:------> %s", response.status_code)
        except requests.exceptions as err:
            logging.info(Back.RED + "\nError: %s", err)
        i += 1
```

As you can see local_folder_for_json_object and json_s3_object_name values are passed from another function and I am using them to open the file and send the request to API.
The line where it prints the json response, it prints an empty response.

```
response.json---------------->{}
```

But its correctly opening the file and getting the ID from it as this line shows this.

```
Constructing URL for externalPk:------> client6666#1-20240318-0957#1-20240318-0957
```

I tried downloading the file from S3 using 2 different methods just to rule out the possibility of incorrect file download, but still no luck.

1. s3.download_file
2. s3.download_fileobj

Any help in diagnosing the problem is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you meant `with open(json_file_name, ...)` ?

Comment: yes, that json file name is the one downloaded from s3 bucket. The json file name itself is with extension ".json.txt". For eg: 4545453.json.txt. I also tried printing the request response and its printed as <Response [200]>

Comment: When I used the debugger in Pycharm, my_json_s3_object_name is shown as <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/Desktop/JSON/200434T203432.json.txt'. I am not sure if that's the reason for an empty json response.